# Errors installing Office Developer Tools for VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

I need to develop SP2013 apps from VS2012. But I'm unable to install the Office Dev tools of VS2012. I downloaded and installed the full VS2012 install (without unchecking a thing) but when I opened it after the install was done, I do not see "Office/SharePoint" as one of the templates under Visual C#. I only see "Office" and "SharePoint" categories.

[image]

So I checked my Control Panel and did not see the tools installed (unless I missed it) Way to go, VS2012 install. Anyways, I then downloaded and tried to install it, but I get several errors when it tries to install.

[image]

I decided to completely remove every facet of VS2012 & VS2013 and reinstall. The same exact things happened. I don't see Office/SharePoint and I get errors trying to install something that should already be there.

Help please.

Comment: Does clicking *View log here* shed any light?

Comment: Na, it just spits out the same error shown in the screenshot. Error 1316